# Snort: How do I get packets to show up?

Tags: snort, ids

I've recently installed Snort and according to the video I used, it should start detecting packets. The problem is that its not even though there are no errors. It looks like this:

```
Decoding Ethernet

        --== Initialization Complete ==--

   ,,_     -*> Snort! <*-
  o"  )~   Version 2.9.16-WIN64 GRE (Build 118)
   ''''    By Martin Roesch & The Snort Team: http://www.snort.org/contact#team
           Copyright (C) 2014-2020 Cisco and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
           Copyright (C) 1998-2013 Sourcefire, Inc., et al.
           Using PCRE version: 8.10 2010-06-25
           Using ZLIB version: 1.2.11

           Rules Engine: SF_SNORT_DETECTION_ENGINE  Version 3.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SSLPP  Version 1.1  <Build 4>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SSH  Version 1.1  <Build 3>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SMTP  Version 1.1  <Build 9>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SIP  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_SDF  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_REPUTATION  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_POP  Version 1.0  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_MODBUS  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_IMAP  Version 1.0  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_GTP  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_FTPTELNET  Version 1.2  <Build 13>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DNS  Version 1.1  <Build 4>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DNP3  Version 1.1  <Build 1>
           Preprocessor Object: SF_DCERPC2  Version 1.0  <Build 3>
Commencing packet processing (pid=16400)
```

But nothing else appears. The rules I currently have in the local.rules file is

```
alert icmp any any -> any any (msg:"Testing ICMP alert"; sid:1000001;)
alert udp any any -> any any (msg:"Testing UDP alert"; sid:1000002;)
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"Testing TCP alert"; sid:1000003;)
```

I'm also currently using Windows 10 which didnt help because a lot of people who asked questions similar to this used VM. Would be grateful for some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying a command like this one:

```sh
snort –i3 -c c:\Snort\etc\snort.conf -A console
```

Where "3" is the number of the interface you're sniffing. Try to change the number of the interface you're sniffing in your command until you get something back.

You can see how many interface you have by typing:

```sh
snort -W
```